# how to covert a time string like "2017-03-24T11:12:04+08:00" to a unix timestamp

Tags: mysql

I know unix_timestamp can do this, like below:

```
SELECT unix_timestamp('2017-03-24T11:12:04+08:00');
```

but, when set a time_zone:

```
SET time_zone='+0:00';   // the timestamp will be: 1490353924
```

or

```
set time_zone='+8:00';   // the timestamp will be: 1490325124
```

So, how to get a timestamp which is always 1490353924 ?

Just like the MySQL data type TIMESTAMP does: No matter what time_zone is, the seconds number is not changed which is always offest from 1970-01-01:00:00:00 utc +0:00.

```
select unix_timestamp(time_stamp_column) from `TABLE_TEST`;  // time_stamp_column is a column of talbe TABLE_TEST, and it's type is TIMESTAMP
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code.

```
set @@global.time_zone = '+00:00';
```

or

```
set @@global.time_zone = '+8:00';
```

Comment: thanks, but what I mean is how to get the same timestamp no matter what the current time zone is.

Comment: I get the answer from other place:
`select unix_timestamp(convert_tz('2017-03-24T11:12:04+08:00', substring('2017-03-24T11:12:04+08:00', 20, 6), @@session.time_zone));`